# Display the currently used files by user

Tags: sharepoint-online

Scenario: i want a web part to show only the currently used files of the user. In my case the log-in user should only see the files he used recently and not of other user.

NOTE:If a file is used by several users,in this case if we can't filter by modified by,if the user is the last one having modified the file he wont see it.
I just want a way to show the user the files he has been working on. I don't want the user to perform additional steps for the solution to work.

Comment: what do you mean by "currently used" ? do you mean "currently checked out" files by current logged in user ?

Comment: very different solutions on form and complexity occurs to me depending on the specific need you have regarding what _"used recently"_ means to you. Could you please clarify if in your specific scenario "used recently" could be "modified by the user"? or you need also one of "viewed (properties), downloaded"? On later case the work needed to detect it are harder; on former the solution could be simpler with a Content Query.

Comment: @nilsandrey what about if a file is used by several users,in this case if we can't filter by modified by,if the user is the last one having modified the file he wont see it . i am interested more with the viewed property

Comment: @GopalZadafiya I don't want the files modified by the user,because if someonelse changes the file,my user wont see it. I just want a way to show the user the files he has been working on

Comment: @KeshavTaurah, you must translate the functional requirement "working on" in terms of the technical elements the framework are offering you. To make a simple solution you should have the account in some metadata field. If not then the solution can't be made with a simpler Content Query, you must implement then a code with the complex logic of detect user "worked with the file" (translated on terms of some modification or reading). Modifications can be detected navigating history, reads can be detected (harder) by enabling Auditing and query it with the API on a custom webpart. How you need it?

Comment: @nilsandrey both modification and read will be great.Any tutorials on how to start coding those functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If your definition of "currently used files of the user" is Created or Modified by the user, then you can use the Relevant Documents web part (in the Content Rollup category).

Comment: Smith - MCT -MVP again,what about if a file is used by several users,in this case if we can't filter by modified by,if the user is the last one having modified the file he wont see it

Comment: The only way to track views, and past access, is via the Auditing features.  These logs are not accessible by any out of the box web parts. While SharePoint on-prem lets you audit/track views, SharePoint Online does not. The closest you may get with SharePoint Online is to train your users to use Delve. If they visit Delve and click "Me" they can see a list of documents they have modified. You will need to test to see what happens when the next person modifies the document. As Delve is search driven, it will never be 100% up to date.

Comment: Smith -MCT - MVP That too complicated. i just want a simple solution to prevent my user from searching the file he need to work by browsing through several folders. I need to display those file on the homepage of SharePoint

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it in a single Document Library, create a view called "My Items" and apply the following:

1. Sort: Modified > Descending (to show the last modified on top)
2. Filter: Modified By = [Me] OR Created By = [Me]
3. Folders: Show all items without folders

Comment: what about if a file is used by several users,in this case if we can't filter by modified by,if the user is the last one having modified the file he wont see it

Comment: Yes indeed Modified By gets replaced each time a item / file is modified. The only way to see modified by history is to look in the item/documents version history if enabled and a view only sees the current version of any item.

Comment: what i want is a webpart that show each user the files they have been working on

Comment: If user ownership is what is needed, just create a people picker column so users can pin their names against an item / file. Then the [Me] filter can be used to filter the content they choose to tag themselves on.

Comment: not the solution  i am hoping for. I don't want the user to perform any manipulation if possible

Comment: How about the Content Rollup > Relevant Documents web part? The description says: Displays documents that are relevant to the current user. Found a site that has more info: http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sharepoint-2013/sharepoint-2013-relevant-documents-web-part.htm

Comment: it uses the modified By filter,same problem i said above